# Ignoring exception checking while using Method.invoke in java

Tags: java, reflection, exception

In a project I am taking part in, there is a plethora of classes each implementing a method called `add` which all work the same way, e.g. `MyVector sum = add(vector1, vector2)`, where `vector1` and `vector2` are both of type `MyVector`. I have no permission to modify of all the classes that have `add`, so I could have make them implement some interface "`IAddable`".

Now, I'd like to make a generic class of the form

```
class Summinator<TVector>
{
    Function<TVector,TVector,TVector> add;

    public Summinator()
    {
        //... somehow get the class of TVector, say cVector
        Method addMethod = cVector.getDeclaredMethod("add", new Class[] {cVector, cVector});
        add = (v1, v2) -> (TVector)addMethod.invoke(null, v1, v2);
    }

    public TVector VeryLargeSum(TVector[] hugePileOfVectors)
    {
        TVector sum = hugePileOfVectors[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < hugePileOfVectors.length; i++)
        {
            sum = add(sum, hugePileOfVectors[i]);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

As the sum is large, I'd like to have a lambda-expression to do the work. I also make type-checking at the initiation time. However, java wants me to check for exceptions every time I invoke the method, so instead of

```
add = (v1, v2) -> (TVector)addMethod.Invoke(null, v1, v2);
```

it forces me to write something like

```
add = (v1, v2) -> 
{
    try {
    return add.invoke(null, v1, v2);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
};
```

I am afraid that this exception-checking will consume lots of machine time, whereas all the objects are in fact quite basic in their nature and the application of `add` is in fact a matter of a handful of flops. If it was C# and all classes in question had an overloaded + operation, I could have solved my problem with System.Linq.Expressions package, using the supported binary operations: there exception checking is not obligatory. But... I am to work in java.

Perhaps, there is some way around to at least ignore exception checking?

Comment: Exception checking doesn't cost *any time* at runtime if the exception is not thrown. So the premise of your question isn't correct. Also note that all Java library method names follow the Java coding conventions, so it's `method.invoke` (lowercase) rather than `method.Invoke`.

Comment: Reflection should be avoided as much as possible.  How many different classes do you have?  You could probably create a `Map<Class<?>, BinaryOperator<TVector>>`.  Also, as Erwin pointed out, you should follow Java conventions, including the convention of using a single capital letter for generic type parameters.

Comment: Sorry for the typo.

Comment: `Map` is the walkaround that I use now, as my method is also to have with built-in types like `int` and `double`. What bothers me is that this can make the project harder to extend, except that I'll have to implement the map not in "`Summatator`" but in some other class that will be accessible by for similar classes. This will anyway mean that, whenever a new kind of "vector" appears, the map is to be modified.

Comment: The root cause of the problem is that apparently you don't have a shared base class with an overridden `add` method, or an interface that they all implement. That is very non-Object Oriented, and if you can't solve that issue, you're going to have to workaround it with ugly hacks. "This will anyway mean that, whenever a new kind of "vector" appears, the map is to be modified." you say - yes, that is a direct result of this bad design (that you may have inherited)

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt In fact it is an inherited bad design which I have unfortunately encountered in both C# and java: you don't have a good base interface for all number classes. Java's Number is a set and not a monoid, group or ring (in math sense) - you can have numbers, but you can't do arithmetic with them. And making home-brewed classes stat just implement basic types is intolerably awful.

And yes, I am bound to other's prior decisions, be they good or bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class, there’s something missing. You are calling `getDeclaredMethod` on a `cVector` that is nowhere in scope. Due to type erasure, a generic class has no possibility to get that `Class` object of the parameterization on its own, so for this class to work correctly, there must be someone instantiating the `Summinator` with the actual type parameterization *and* passing the appropriate `Class` object, e.g.

```
Summinator<Actual> actualSumminatior = new Summinator<>(Actual.class);
```

The cleanest solution is to change the `Summinator` class to let this instantiating code pass the intended `add` function in the first place:

```
class Summinator<TVector>
{
    final BinaryOperator<TVector> add;

    public Summinator(BinaryOperator<TVector> addFunction)
    {
        add = addFunction;
    }

    public TVector VeryLargeSum(TVector[] hugePileOfVectors)
    {
        TVector sum = hugePileOfVectors[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < hugePileOfVectors.length; i++)
        {
            sum = add.apply(sum, hugePileOfVectors[i]);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

and change the caller(s) to

```
Summinator<Actual> actualSumminatior = new Summinator<>(Actual::add);
```

That’s all.

But note that the entire operation of `VeryLargeSum` can be simplified to

```
return Arrays.stream(hugePileOfVectors).reduce(Actual::add)
    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("empty array"));
```

at the use site, rendering the entire `Summinator` obsolete.

---

If the calling code is an unchangeable legacy code base and you have to live with the `Class` input, you can generate the equivalent to method references dynamically:

```
class Summinator<TVector>
{
    final BinaryOperator<TVector> add;

    public Summinator(Class<TVector> cVector)
    {
        MethodHandles.Lookup l = MethodHandles.lookup();
        MethodType addSignature = MethodType.methodType(cVector, cVector, cVector);
        try
        {
            MethodHandle addMethod = l.findStatic(cVector, "add", addSignature);
            add = (BinaryOperator<TVector>)LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(l, "apply",
                  MethodType.methodType(BinaryOperator.class),
                  addSignature.erase(), addMethod, addSignature)
                .getTarget().invokeExact();
        }
        catch(RuntimeException|Error t)
        {
            throw t;
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("not an appropriate type "+cVector, t);
        }
    }

    public TVector VeryLargeSum(TVector[] hugePileOfVectors)
    { // if hugePileOfVectors is truly huge, this can be changed to parallel execution
        return Arrays.stream(hugePileOfVectors).reduce(add)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("empty array"));
    }
}
```

Note that both solutions likely run faster than the `Method.invoke` based, but not due to the absence of exception handling in the function, but rather because invocation through Reflection is expensive in general.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some utility that will make it simple to sum all of the instances of different objects in array you should make use of function references and streams in Java 8.

Let's assume that you have some class `MyVector` with static `add` function:

```
/**
 * Class with static add method.
 */
public class MyVector {

    public static MyVector add(MyVector one, MyVector two) {
        return new MyVector();
    }

}
```

Then you can do the array summing the following way:

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Summing {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyVector[] myValues = new MyVector[]{/* values */};
        MyVector sum = Stream.of(myValues).reduce(MyVector::add).get();
    }

}
```

The situation gets a bit more tricky if `add` is an instance method. But assuming that it doesn't depend on object properties:

```
/**
 * Class with instance add method.
 */
public class OtherVector {

    public OtherVector add(OtherVector one, OtherVector two) {
        return new OtherVector();
    }

}
```

You can apply something of the kind:

```
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Summing {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        OtherVector[] otherValues = new OtherVector[]{/* values */};
        // If add is an instance method than you need to decide what instance you want to use
        BinaryOperator<OtherVector> otherAdd = new OtherVector()::add;
        OtherVector sum = Stream.of(otherValues).reduce(otherAdd).get();
    }

}
```

Comment: The main idea was to have a generic "`Summatator`" class, for I am likely to instantiate several of them at runtime, each for a different kind of vectors. Suppose all the vectors do have a static `add` method. Then a silly question: will the following code work? (Sure I can try myself)

`import java.util.stream.Stream; public class Summing<V> {public V sum(V[] values) {return Stream.of(values).reduce(V::add).get();}`

Comment: When `add` is an instance method, it likely has only one parameter, to add `this` with the argument. In that case, `MyVector::add` still is the right thing to do.